# Return type for non-existing column in Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

My code generates dynamic columns for some table based on some condition.
The column may or may not exist.

So I am doing -

```
cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Dynamic_Column_Name"))
```

The api for *cur.getColumnIndex("Dynamic_Column_Name")* says -

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the
>   column doesn't exist.

So if `Dynamic_Column_Name` is not a column in my table then it will be--

```
cur.getString(-1)
```

The api for *cur.getString(-1)* says -

> Returns the value of the requested column as a String. The result and
>   whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null
>   or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

So what is the return type in my case or will it through some exception ?

Is there any best way to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get an exception. Specifically:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row n, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

To avoid it, check the column index is not -1 before using it.